# Generate function calls using combinations from two lists

Tags: c++, macros, c++17

I want to test a whole lot of different message types, where each message type can contain different kinds of objects. I have

```
template <typename ObjectT> class MessageRequest1;
template <typename ObjectT> class MessageReply1;
...
template <typename ObjectT> class MessageRequestN;
template <typename ObjectT> class MessageReplyN;
```

And similarly, I have a whole lot of object types..
I have template functions that can test combinations of types:

```
template <MessageType, ObjectType> bool TestFunction(void);
```

What I want to do, is have a system of macros (or something else) that can call my TestFunction with all combinations of MessageTypes and ObjectTypes. I'm envisioning something like:

```
ADD_MESSAGE_TYPE(1);
...
ADD_MESSAGE_TYPE(N);

ADD_OBJECT_TYPE(Object1);
...
ADD_OBJECT_TYPE(ObjectN);
```

Which would generate calls to TestFunction, with all object types for all message types. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are the `MessageRequestN`/`MessageReplyN` related to the `MessageType` template parameter? Or why do they matter at all to the question?

Comment: Do you mean `template<template<class>class MessageType, class ObjectType> bool TestFunction(void);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to store lists of those types in variadic wrapper classes and then use fold expressions to generate the function calls for each type combination:

```
template<class ... Ts>
struct wrapper
{};

template<template<class> class ... Ts>
struct templateWrapper
{};


using ObjectTypes = wrapper<
    Object1,
    //...
    ObjectN
    >;

using MessageTypes = templateWrapper<
    MessageRequest1,
    MessageReply1,
    //...
    MessageRequestN,
    MessageReplyN
    >;

template<class MessageType, class ObjectType>
bool TestFunction(void);

template<template<class> class MessageType, class ... ObjectTypes>
bool callForAllYall_helper2(wrapper<ObjectTypes...>*)
{
    return (TestFunction<MessageType<ObjectTypes>, ObjectTypes>() && ...);
}

template<template<class> class ... MessageTypes>
bool callForAllYall_helper1(templateWrapper<MessageTypes...>*)
{
    return (callForAllYall_helper2<MessageTypes>((ObjectTypes*)(nullptr)) && ...);
}

bool callTestFunctionForAllYall()
{
    return callForAllYall_helper1((MessageTypes*)(nullptr));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Cj6cDS

No macros needed!

Check the generated assembly to verify that this does indeed call `TestFunction<MessageType<ObjectType>, ObjectType>` for every pair of `MessageType, ObjectType`. I `and`ed the return values together since that's presumably what you want. You could replace the `&&` with `,` to discard (all but the last) values instead.

To abstract further and reuse the same code for different test functions is actually a bit harder, because you cannot pass templated functions as template parameters (only their instantiations, which is not helpful here). You'll have to wrap all your test functions in a struct (or lambda) that can be passed as a type argument (and pass that through to the innermost helper function).

Answer (score 1):

For some reason @Max's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54407601) is not zero cost (generates `test` and `je` instructions). Below is my zero cost c++14 version.
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/kwgMZK

```
#include <type_traits>

//User Objects
template<class Obj>
struct Msg1;
template<class Obj>
struct Msg2;
template<class Obj>
struct Msg3;

struct Obj1;
struct Obj2;
struct Obj3;
struct Obj4;

template<class MsgType, class ObjType>
void TestFunction(void);

namespace helper {
    template<template<class Obj> class Msg>
    struct TMsg {
        template<class O>
        using RMsg = Msg<O>;
    };

    template<class... Type>
    struct Wrap{};

    template<class Msg>
    void caller1(Msg, Wrap<>){}

    template<class Msg, class Obj, class... Objs>
    void caller1(Msg m, Wrap<Obj, Objs...> O) {
        Obj o;
        using TMsgL = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*m)>::type;
        using ObjL = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*o)>::type;
        using MsgL = typename TMsgL::template RMsg<ObjL>;
        TestFunction<MsgL, ObjL>();
        Wrap<Objs...> r;
        caller1(m, r);
    }

    template<class... Objs>
    void caller(Wrap<>, Wrap<Objs...>){}

    template<class Msg, class... Msgs, class... Objs>
    void caller(Wrap<Msg, Msgs...> M, Wrap<Objs...> O){
        Msg m;
        caller1(m, O);
        Wrap<Msgs...> ML;
        caller(ML, O);
    }
}

void foo(){
    using Msgs = helper::Wrap<helper::TMsg<Msg1>*, helper::TMsg<Msg2>*, helper::TMsg<Msg3>*>;
    using Objs = helper::Wrap<Obj1*, Obj2*, Obj3*, Obj4*>;
    Msgs m;
    Objs o;
    caller(m, o);
}
```

Generated Assembly

```
foo():
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    void TestFunction<Msg1<Obj1>, Obj1>()
        call    void TestFunction<Msg1<Obj2>, Obj2>()
        call    void TestFunction<Msg1<Obj3>, Obj3>()
        call    void TestFunction<Msg1<Obj4>, Obj4>()
        call    void TestFunction<Msg2<Obj1>, Obj1>()
        call    void TestFunction<Msg2<Obj2>, Obj2>()
        call    void TestFunction<Msg2<Obj3>, Obj3>()
        call    void TestFunction<Msg2<Obj4>, Obj4>()
        call    void TestFunction<Msg3<Obj1>, Obj1>()
        call    void TestFunction<Msg3<Obj2>, Obj2>()
        call    void TestFunction<Msg3<Obj3>, Obj3>()
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     void TestFunction<Msg3<Obj4>, Obj4>()
```

Comment: My version is not zero cost because I don't just discard all the return values. The assumption here being that the `bool` return value is of some use (like "did the test succeed"). Replace the `&&` in my answer with `,` as I said and it [becomes "zero cost"](https://godbolt.org/z/PjVrcH). Nevertheless, your answer is helpful because it is C++ 14.